# Matching on iptables rules containing timestamp

Tags: bash, ubuntu, iptables

I am installing iptable rules with a timestamp value:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.0.0.3 -m comment --comment "Timestamp=`date +%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S`" -j DROP
```

which results in the following iptable rule:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.0.0.3 -m comment --comment "Timestamp=2018/02/26-22:34:15" -j DROP
```

now I'm not able to find a way to test on existing rules:

```
$ iptables -C INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.0.0.3 -j DROP
```

I've tried using cut command and with egrep, but nothing seems to work for me.

```
$ iptables -S INPUT | cut  -d' ' --complement -s -f7-10
```

How I'm supposed to test on existing iptables rules containing a timestamp value?

Comment: What do you mean by 'test on'?  What exactly are you trying to do with the `iptables` rules?  Are you trying to see what rules were added on a given timestamp?

Comment: FOr what it's worth, `-C` will only return a clean 'exit' code of 0 if it finds something *if* the entire specification of the rule is matched explicitly.  Not partially matched, but fully matched.  Using `-C` is not going to be a valid mechanism for checking if things exist.

Comment: @Thomas, by test I mean "Check"  to see whether  a  rule matching the specification does exist in the selected chain, I am setting up iptables rules for blocking certain IP addresses, but each blocking rule should be timestamped indicating when it was exactly installed. For installing new rules, I need to test whether or not rule with the given specification exist, it can easily be achieved with this command: iptables -C INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.0.0.3 -j DROP, but the presence of timestamp is making it complicated.

Comment: true, -C returns 0 exit code if given specification matches 100%, problem is how do I know "-m comment --comment "Timestamp=2018/02/26-22:34:15" (programmatically or with a regex possibly) this portion of an installed iptable rule while "Checking" for existing rules without listing and traversing through hundreds of thousands of installed rules.

Answer (score 1):

The `-C` function only works with **exact** matches against rules.

That is, if the rule I added is `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m comment "DropSSH" -j DROP`, then `iptables -C INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m comment "DropSSH" -j DROP` will match and the `-C` will not error out.  However, there is *not* an exact match for `iptables -C INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP` so it will fail to drop.

---

The only way to really see if a specification like the one you're looking for exists *and* taking into account partial rule matches would be piecemeal `grep` filtering.

Such that:

```
iptables -S INPUT | grep -i '-p tcp' | grep -i '--dport 22' | grep -i '-j DROP'
```

would probably match on any rules allowing port 22 over TCP.  However, as you can see, this is nontrivial and can cause issues.  `cut`ting the data won't help much either.  The tricky part about this is that you have to split up what you're searching for into individual bits to do the `grep`.

---

The other alternative to adding the timestamps in the *comments* is to version-control the `iptables` rules so that every time you update and save the rules, you update version controlled copies of the rulesets with individual revisions so you can over-time see what was changed.  And by *not* having timestamps in comments, you can properly use `-C`, and if you need to see who made a change, you can go back into the version control data to see who made what change when.